# Triple boot MBR with GRUB avoid Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, mbr

I installed a triple boot system (Windows 10 Home 21H1/Windows 7 Pro/Debian 11), on three different partitions on a partitioned disk in MBR, and at boot I can start each system without problem. But in GRUB menu all the Windows systems are accessible from a single entry named "Windows 10" (in reason of the first installation) which run **Windows Boot Manager** and let me choose the Windows' system I want to boot. So 2 menus displayed for boot each Windows system. It is not practical.

I asked to myself if there is a solution to make the Windows entries from WBM directly accessible from GRUB menu without go through WBM. I searched and tested a lot of different solutions but none worked.

I believe it is possible but I do not know how ...

The last attempt I tried :

```bash
root@host:~# lsblk -lo NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID
sda               
sda1 ntfs   W10H  7A42F6E942F6A8D1
sda2 ntfs   W7P   0628B81B28B80C25
sda3 ext4         a696a4ab-3120-4028-bd87-c2aaa40499bd
...  
root@host:~# cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
...
menuentry "Windows 7" --class windows --class os {
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ntfs
   insmod ntldr
   set root='(hd0,msdos2)'   
   search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 0628B81B28B80C25
   ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
   chainloader +1
}
root@host:~# update-grub
```

And when I booted this entry, I got :
`error : /bootmgr file not available`

---

As @telcoM suggested me, I asked for help in the global section of SE. I finally resolved my question with the help of @oldfred here and @Tom Yan [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1756042/make-linux-grub-run-directly-multiple-windows-systems) where I detailed my implementation.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1718093/) (EFI instead of BIOS). In case we ever find a method of booting a specific Windows installation via GRUB (directly or indirectly via `ntldr` or `bootmgfw`), I am interested in using it.

Comment: It can be done. But both Windows installs must be in primary partitions each with its own boot files & BCD. Typically done as one install, move boot flag & second install. If primary partitions, you can move boot flag & do a repair so second install has boot files, then move flag back. Grub does not use boot flag, it looks for boot files. Windows uses boot flag. Similarly with UEFI create temporary second ESP& reinstall Windows boot files. UEFI needs one ESP, but grub can find Windows boot files in another FAT32 partition.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1271600

Comment: Thank you too oldfred :D

Comment: Please don't cross-post the [same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727215/triple-boot-mbr-with-grub-avoid-windows-boot-manager) on multiple SE sites. This is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @doneal24 : That was not my intention but the questions are not the same, but they are bound and they complete each other. Maybe I could re-title them to emphasize the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GRUB `ntldr` command is currently looking for a file named `bootmgr` on the second partition of the first HDD, but that file does not exist there. Windows 10 and Windows 7 can both use the same Windows Boot Manager: in your system, they are currently configured to do just that, and the boot manager is configured to present a menu of the available OSs. Installers of modern Windows OSs look for existing Windows boot managers, and if one exists, will add the freshly-installed OS to the menu of the existing boot manager instead of installing another instance of it.

Since GRUB cannot pass any OS selection information to the Windows Boot Manager (or rather, the WBM cannot accept input from any other bootloader, only directly from the user), you would need to have two instances of it on your system: one configured to boot Windows 10 only, and another configured to boot Windows 7 only. Then you could use the GRUB menu to select which boot manager to use, and so select the Windows version.

Installing a second copy of Windows Boot Manager would be outside the scope of this Unix&Linux.SE: if you need advice on that, you might want to ask on [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help :D. I also tried to directly boot the W10 system with no more success. I just understood what your answer implies. From Windows I deleted the WBM's W7 entry and after reboot, as there was no more other system to boot, selecting the GRUB Windows menu item starts automatically W10 without WBM. Also I just read that there is "a priori" [no way to boot Windows without WBM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328223/getting-rid-of-the-windows-boot-manager-when-dual-booting/1328229#1328229). So your answer seems to lead me in the right direction with a Windows solution